# When I User "PhotoChooserTask" and Invoke Show(), My Project is collapse have no idea. help me

Tags: windows-phone-7

When My Project Into Album From Page,I don't choose picture, my project is collapse. 
this is my Code,please help me.

```
PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
photoChooserTask.Show();
phoneChooserTask.Completed += (se, ev) => { //Nothing to do };
```

this is my Exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

ExceptionObject = {"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.String]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is application deactivation, not in photo chooser task. Try to press `Start` button and you will see the same.

As `Exception` says, that you have a `Stack` in class that is trying to serialize while deactivating. `Stack` can't be serialized with `Data Contracts`.

You can disable it serialization with `[IgnoreDataMemberAttribute]` or save it manually as a `List` while deactivation and restore it to `Stack` after

Comment: I remove all Stack , but still collapse

Comment: Oh my god, I find the Stack.. Remove it , my project is work.  thank you so much